# Percentage symbol at the end of git log --pretty=format

Tags: git, zsh

When I run

```
git log --pretty=format:%s -1
```

I get this feedback:

```
Merge branch 'feature/416_NewTemplate' into develop%
```

A percentage symbol, black text on white background, appears at the end for some reason. I can't find why. 
I removed all my gitconfig aliases because I thought it came from there, no change.

It is not inside my commit's message because the percentage symbol appears at the end of all commits :

```
git log --pretty=format:'%s' -2
Merge branch 'feature/416_NewTemplate' into develop
ft(#416/NewTemplate): resolve merge conflict%
```

No percentage symbol when I try

```
git log --pretty=short
```

Git version 2.17.0 on Windows babun shell zsh.

Comment: Didn't reproduce that on a git 1.7.10.4 (debian bash). Are the other pretty format placeholders working OK?

Comment: It seems to come from the output of "pretty" option, because when I grep on it the "%" dissapear :

git log -2 --pretty=format:'%h'
09b2b3c1
95da55ac%

But:
git log -2 --pretty=format:'%h' | grep 95
95da55ac

Comment: Can't reproduce with 2.16.3 on OS X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That `%` is zsh indicating that the last line of output wasn't properly terminated (no newline). See also http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting.

As described in [`man git-log`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats), you probably want `--pretty=tformat:%s`, not `format:`.

> - *tformat:*
>
>   The *tformat:* format works exactly like *format:*, except that it provides "terminator" semantics instead of "separator" semantics. In other words, each commit has the message terminator character (usually a newline) appended, rather than a separator placed between entries. This means that the final entry of a single-line format will be properly terminated with a new line, just as the "oneline" format does.